# Integrate two types of Gregorian and solar (shamsi,jalali) calendar with each other in calendar view

Tags: java, android, calendar, calendarview

i just wondering if we can integrate two types of calendar in android(like solar and Gregorian) with each other and show them in one calendar view
is it possible even?

its a example of what i am saying:

[image: example]

Comment: I don't know, but almost certainly you would need a custom library for this.  Try searching around and see what you can find.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i searched for libs but it doesnt provide what i want.they are just seprated libs for Greogorian and solar calendars.i will wait to see if someone know something about this.but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for anyone who has this problem i solved it by making a custom calendar view with Grid Layout and create two calendar class by help of icu4j library(on for Gregorian Calendar and one for Persian Calendar and set them on my view)

lib: http://site.icu-project.org/download/59

Comment: hi, I'm trying to create my custom Persian calendar, and I couldn't find a good library for this. can you explain more about how to use icu4j library?! how can I fill my view?! our if your project is on git, please insert a git link so we can use it. thank you.